# Which directive does the attribute belong to when there are multiple directives in the same tag in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a question about directives.

When I define two or more directives and put them in the same element, how can I tell which directive an attribute belongs to? Will it belong to all of the directives?

Something like this:

```
<dir1  dir2  attr1="attrvalue"></dir1>
```

Can I access attr1 in both dir1 and dir2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether you can access the attribute in the link function of both directives, the answer is yes.

At most one of these two directives can have an isolate scope.  That directive would also be able to access the attribute with its isolate scope.  So for example, you could have:

```
.directive("dir2", function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attr) {
        attr.attr1 == "attrvalue";
    };
})
.directive("attr1", function () {
    return {
        scope: {attr1: "@"}
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, another question is if both of dir1 and dir2 have templates, which one will be applied?

Comment: [`Multiple directives [dir1, dir2] asking for template on:`](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFM9599haQs4D0cYXlg6?p=preview) -- It is recommended that templates be reserved for element directives and this is probably a good reason for that.